# Build for Wizard in Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

Are there any very effective combo builds for a Wizard in D3? So far i'm using quite a bit of a mix and sometimes i feel my build isn't really up to standard.

Can anyone recommend me any builds that they think its good and why (or how to use them)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [D3 Solo Wizard Builds?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69286/d3-solo-wizard-builds)

Comment: sorry, didn't know. but that question isnt really answered as well.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hit and run build for solo wizard (lvl 58)

LC.Magic Missile | Seeker
  (you don't have time in difficult situations to target the mobs :P)
RC.Arcane Orb | Tap the Source
  (Decent splash damage)

1. Teleport | Reversal
   (You have a second chance to get yourself behind the mobs with reversal but be
   careful not to get in the middle of the fight)
2. Blizzard | Snowbound
   (cast Blizzard in front of you and run back so that mobs get showered)
3. Energy Armor | Force Armor
   (the rune does the trick! real life savior!)
4. Mirror Image | Mimics
   (Get the mobs destructed while you hit them from afar)

P1.Blur (self explanatory)
P2.Cold Blooded  (bizzed mobs get more damage)
P3.Galvanizing Ward or Arcane Dynamo

http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/wizard#acQlOP!aWf!cYbbYc

Cast blizzard fall back hit with missiles and orbs. When they get too close teleport or mirror image to distract them. I am usually the only one to be left alive with this strategy in multiplayer games.

Comment: i use 2-hand weapons with this. you don't need attack speed cause you are always on the run. you need to his slow but hard

Answer (score 1):

It is extremely effective to use Venom Hydra and Blizzard together. With a high DPS, you can safely and easily kill most bosses/elites/champions just with those 2 skills and Magic Weapon active. They key is that the pools of venom from the hydra stack damage, so a monster frozen in the blizzard will start to take multiple pool hits per second. Diamond Skin is always useful as a "Oh, crap" button.

Here's my build at 52:

- LC: Electrocute + Chain Lightning
- RC: Arcane Orb + Tap the Source
- 1: Hydra + Venom Hydra
- 2: Blizzard + Frozen Solid
- 3: Diamond Skin + Crystal Shell
- 4: Magic Weapon + Force Weapon
- P1: Blur
- P2: Glass Cannon
- P3: Evocation

Answer (score 0):

I think i've got a effective one here,

1. diamond skin / reflect dmg
2. familiar / +dmg
3. magic weapon boost / +dmg and knockback chance
4. frost shield / reflect dmg
   LMB. living lightning
   RMB. blizzard

Passives
Blur
20% to chilled or frozen targets (I forgot the name)
Paralysis

Discuss. Worked pretty well for me.

Comment: Works where? In Inferno? Also this isn't a discussion forum...

Comment: I'm just asking. I'm using this for Hell.