# Diablo 3 Wizard Skills/Build

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Solo Wizard Builds?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69286/solo-wizard-builds)

I have recently switched from Diablo 2 to 3 and the new way the skills evolve is messing with me a little (automatically things unlock on certain levels versus in the past choosing what you want to add levels to).

Due to all skills having comparable levels now, it is easier to bounce around in what you wish to use (especially when something weak gets a new rune making it more powerful).

My current character is a wizard and I currently like to use Electrocute (to attack multiple enemies), Diamond Skin (otherwise I'd die quickly), and then pretty much any combo of Wave of Force, Hydra, Blizzard, or Meteor.  Sometimes I'd throw in the Familiar but never found it very effective.

I guess my question is: Is this a good build? and What combo would actually work best?  **Either solo or in a group.**

I have a lot of trouble comparing the strengths of different attacks since they're all nearly the same level, whereas in d2 you used the same few things the whole time because it's where you put your skill points.

Comment: I've looked at a lot of the wizard build questions and didn't really find one comparable to mine

Comment: How does your question differ from, say, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69286/solo-wizard-builds?  Or http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73130/inferno-stats-to-get-through-act-2-as-a-wizard?

Comment: Most of your question is a dup of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69286/solo-wizard-builds, so I am voting to close it as such. Re. your skills, pretty much any combo will work till Hell - and I'd advise you to try different combos so that you learn the pros & cons quickly in earlier difficulties.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73130/inferno-stats-to-get-through-act-2-as-a-wizard doesn't seem to apply at all. and http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69286/solo-wizard-builds is just for a solo build which i don't have enough knowledge to tell if that's what mine is best at

Comment: Shouldn't you know what your build is best at?  You are, after all, playing it.  If you're looking for build advice, the two questions I linked to should help you with that.  Your question doesn't tell us what you're looking for, beyond, "Is my build good?".

Comment: I was mostly looking for whether or not anyone had experience with a similar build and could give information about which to use in which scenario (group or not, boss or not) but i guess ill just figure it out

Comment: @TMP Before I uninstalled the atrocity that is this game, I used a similar build to solo Hell/early Inferno. It works on both mobs and bosses, though you should always adapt your skills as necessary (i.e. Meteor/Blizzard isn't really useful against Belial). Also, you should try using the Familiar that gives you +11% damage as it pushes up your DPS a lot. That being said, I still don't think this question covers anything additional that other diablo 3 wizard build questions on this site haven't already .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i just thought it did 20% damage or something similar, but i guess i didn't check its runes.  if you guys so wish i shall delete this upon any request.

Comment: There's an option to turn on detailed tooltips.  Under Gameplay, I believe?  It will tell you how much damage your skills are doing.  Perhaps that might help.

Comment: Upto you whether to delete or not; atleast it hasn't got negative votes and will likely be closed soon. More pertinent - you should really head over to chat, much easier to get friendly advice on questions that would be too localized or subjective to post :)