# How can I build a melee/kite wizard?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

I'm running a  1/2 melee, 1/2 kite wizard build. The build is:

Passives:

- Astral Presence
- Galvanizing Ward
- Temporal Flux

Offense spells:

- Arcane orb (celestial)
- Hydra (Poison)
- Blizzard (stark winter)

Defensive skills:

- Teleport (fracture)
- Energy Armor (prismatic)

Buff skills:

- Magic Weapon (force weapon)

I can farm act 2 inferno with this build, but most elites rough me up in act 3 though. Any suggestions on how I can improve my build?

Comment: Have you looked at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69286/solo-wizard-builds, or http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73130/inferno-stats-to-get-through-act-2-as-a-wizard?  Those might give you an idea on what to do.

Comment: Not in A3, but your armor/res seems quite low for going melee.

Comment: Is this a little too localized? A broader question on build viability would've been better.