# Why Twister over Piercing Orb

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

My question is, what is the reasoning behind using twister, is there a large advantage over using something like piercing orb? Is it an AP sink?  If so, what is the advantage over using the Arcane Orb that pierces.

Comment: Currently, this sounds like a build question, which [we already have](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69286/solo-wizard-builds).  Stats are [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/72705/what-stats-are-best-for-casters-wizard-witch-doctor-doing-inferno).  I'd recommend paring the question down to, "When do you prioritize Twister over Piercing Orb?".

Comment: I prefer wicked wind myself, but that's just me and I haven't put too much effort into my wizard beyond act 1 inferno

Comment: It's quite a jump, I'm finding personally.  Act 1 is facerollingly easy, whereas Act 2 is quite a bit harder.  My friend who plays a barb can at least survive decently well with equivalent gear / skill level.

Comment: I meant limit the entire question to just that question. :P  Asking for build advice invites discussion, which doesn't work so well with the question and answer format of Arqade.  Remember, we're here to *help*, but not play your game for you.  They also invite lots of discussion.  Hence why I linked the solo wizards build question.

Comment: I figured, but I was keeping the context, re-editted =)

Comment: Context is important, I agree.  But this question can stand on it's own, and is a good question, in my opinion.

Comment: Because "left hand blue" is a lot more fun than "left hand piercing agony". ;p

Comment: Haha, the other thing I think is, since you're usually bunching up the mobs into one little area, having a slow moving tornado make their way through them while frozen is more damage over time rather than the big front end blast of an Arcane Orb, or a Piercing Orb.

Comment: sounds like you've just answered your own question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I've spent an absurdly long time playing wizard, I can answer this with some confidence.

Energy Twister, specifically the Wicked Wind rune, has several major advantages over Arcane Orb (whatever rune).

- It does a lot of micro ticks while staying in place during its entire duration, this allows you to have multiple chances of proccing an 'on crit hit' effect such as gaining Arcane Power or triggering Critical Mass
- It can hit targets multiple times because it stays in place
- It scales well with higher attack speeds
- It can stack in the same location by casting it multiple times

This is most commonly used in CM Wizard builds as they rely on many proc effects.

Arcane Orb will only hit a target once, so your chances of proccing an effect is much smaller.

Comment: Yeah, I asked this when the game had come out basically.